# How to take a user input as if it was entered as code?

Tags: python, string, input

I'm trying to have a function return a polynomial in a specific format when the user enters it with an input command. However, even using eval(input()), which I understand is terrible practice, gets it caught in a loop. Below is my code:

```
def func(x):
    function = eval(input("enter a string in the format (x - 3) * (x - 5) * (x - 7) + 85")) #should run this as code so horid security, but still busted
    return function
```

I want this to operate as if it read:

```
def func(x):
return (x - 3) * (x - 5) * (x - 7) + 85
```

if the user were to enter that function, but also work if a user entered any polynomial in that format.

This seems general, and I thought at minimum I could cheat it with an eval(input()), but using an eval gets the program caught in a loop where the user is prompted to enter the function indefinitely

Comment: This works for me (Python 3).

Comment: Please read [mcve]

Comment: This code works as long as x is defined.

Comment: It is defined within the function func. So this example itself should work.

Comment: @abccd That may not be the best way to describe the issue, but it gets caught in an infinite loop where it prompts the user for the function as many times as they will answer and will not continue the program as shown here (http://imgur.com/a/uBjxG)

Answer (score 2):

`eval` only evaluates expressions. You can define a function in an expression with `lambda`:

```
f = eval('lambda x: ' + input())
```

This is equivalent to `def f(x): return ...`

Answer (score 1):

How to created user inputted function.

```
import functools
formula = input('enter formula.')
f = functools.partial(eval, formula)
```

Now f is your polynomial function that you would call by doing this.

```
result = f([arg1, arg2, arg3, argN])
```